# Understanding Meteor JS File Structure and Accessing ALL Folders

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am using NPM (Node.js) to try and traverse ALL of the folders in my Meteor project.
However, with my node.js code, I can only seem to access these folders in Meteor:
1.) server
2.) lib
3.) private

I cannot find:
1.) client
2.) public
3.) other folders I added just to the project just to experiment.

The code I use to list the directories are in a .js file inside the server method.
Here is the code I used:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var dir = './';
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
```

and I get the following printed to the console:

```
I20141208-15:18:24.272(8)? [ 'app',
I20141208-15:18:24.272(8)?   'assets',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'boot.js',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'config.json',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'node_modules',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'npm',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'npm-shrinkwrap.json',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'package.json',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'packages',
I20141208-15:18:24.273(8)?   'program.json',
I20141208-15:18:24.274(8)?   'start.sh' ]
```

How can I access the client folder, public folder, etc.???
After all, these folders and the files inside are ultimately in the 'server' too but maybe in a different level.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current working directory of a Node.JS process Meteor app is :

```
.meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

The content of your client-side app will be located at :

```
.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app
```

If you want to access this folder in server-side Node you'll need to do something like :

```
var clientFilesDir=process.cwd()+"/../web.browser/app";
var clientFiles=fs.readdirSync(clientFilesDir);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the root directory through the **PWD** environment variable.  Reading environment variables in Meteor is done through the `process.env` object.  I'm not sure how this works in windows, though.

```
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var dir = process.env.PWD;
  var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
```